# Android 14 ML-KIT Firebase Remote Model Download Issue

Tags: android

**Android 14 Firebase Remote Model Download Issue**.
Can someone help me here? I'm using ML-Kit and the Firebase Link to download a remote model from firebase. It seems the library is not compatible with Android 14.
Does anyone know a workaround how to fix this?

//Code:

```
val firebaseModelSource = FirebaseModelSource.Builder("MODELNAME").build()
val model = CustomRemoteModel.Builder(firebaseModelSource).build()
RemoteModelManager.getInstance().download(model, DownloadConditions.Builder().build())
```

//Lib versions:

```
// ML
implementation("com.google.mlkit:object-detection:17.0.0")
implementation("com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-custom:17.0.1")
implementation("com.google.mlkit:linkfirebase:17.0.0")

//Camera
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.3")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.3")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.3")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.3")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.3.0-beta02")
```

//Exception for downloading model:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ****: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
                    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
                    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
                    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5684)
                    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1852)
                    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1792)
                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:767)
                    at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.RemoteModelDownloadManager.zzj(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:3)
```

//second execution different exception:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Hash does not match with expected
                at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:3)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.internal.model.zzg.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:1)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.internal.model.zzc.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
                at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8171)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
             Caused by: com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Hash does not match with expected
                at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.RemoteModelFileManager.moveModelToPrivateFolder(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:24)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.RemoteModelDownloadManager.zzi(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:7)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.model.RemoteModelDownloadManager.isModelDownloadedAndValid(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:11)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.internal.model.zzg.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:1)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.internal.model.zzf.call(Unknown Source:4)
                at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzg.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.0.0:1)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```